# Cannot send commands to SMS Modem after a long time

Tags: c#, serial-port, modem, sms-gateway

I have 1 a sms modem, connected to the computer via COM port (USB-to-Serial Prolific Comm Port).
I use C# to connect to SMS Modem as follows:

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort();
_serialPort.PortName = comPort;
_serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
_serialPort.DataBits = 8;
_serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
_serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
_serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
_serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
_serialPort.WriteTimeout = 2000;
_serialPort.Open();

// Send AT command to check connection
byte[] data = UtilityFunctions.StringToByteASCII("AT\r");
_serialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length); --> OK
```

However, If I remain connected without close during 8 hours, I can not send commands to the modem again. 
I must withdraw the modem from the computer and plug again for using it.
Why it was so. Please help me!

Comment: What happens when "You cannot send commands to modem"? Does it throw exception during Write method call? If you have handled DataReceived event, does it get invoked?

Comment: It doesn't throw exception during write method call. DataReceived event doesn't get invoked.

Comment: Can we know the brand of the SMS modem you are using? Does your computer go on a Sleep or Hibernate mode while your application is running?